# Buttons not inheriting parent div font-size

Tags: html, css

Using React, I have a block like:

```
  <div id="main">
    0
    <button className="counter-button" onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
    <button className="counter-button" onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
  </div>
```

I add a style like

```
        #main {
            margin: 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
```

This works on the value, but the + and - signs don't get bigger. Adding

```
        .counter-button {
            margin-left: 10px;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
```

makes the font bigger. Why doesn't the div style get inherited by children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most form elements (`input, select, textarea, button`) don't inherit font properties in CSS by default, you have to specify it. http://jsfiddle.net/pEedc/184/

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use **attribute selector** like this

```
[className='counter-button'] {
      font-size: 35px;
    }
```

You need to write multiple selector with separate comma to apply same **font size** on div and button, check the snippet below:

```css
#main {
  margin: 20px;
}
[className='counter-button'] {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
/*For equal font size for both*/

#main,
[className='counter-button'] {
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  0
  <button className="counter-button" onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
  <button className="counter-button" onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: forgot to mention it's React

Comment: You mean react.js? if yes then I guess this is not about react this is common concept of css. this will resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

change your `className` to `class` then you can change the font

```css
   #main {
            margin: 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
   #main .counter-button{
       font-size:35px;
     }
       .counter-button {
            margin-left: 10px;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
          }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    0
    <button class="counter-button" onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
    <button class="counter-button" onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: className this JSX